# ffmpeg 1.0.7 takes minute to create a thumbnail on "broken" video file but other files are seconds to create thumbnail

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I've been using ffmpeg 1.0.7 for over 450GB (cca 400 files) for creating thumbnails and grabbing video-file information. It tooks me like 1-2 seconds to create 10 thumbnails from ~8GB file. But now I've got some 'broken' video file (672 MB) which creates me 1 thumbnail over a minute, 10 thumbnails its over 10 minutes -> my server burns:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 9769 www-data  20   0  395m  28m 7212 R 157.0  0.4   0:04.99 ffmpeg
```

I opened the file in Windows Media Player and getting blank screen while -> video file is weird, opened it in VLC and it wrote me: *`Because this AVI file index is broken or missing, seeking will not work correctly. VLC won't repair your file but can temporary fix this problem by building an index in memory.`* I've clicked 'Play as is' and it plays the video file correctly, however my webserver burns because of FFmpeg and PHP waits for the return from `exec();` command. Thumbnails are also created fine after 10 minutes, but how can I fix this problem or to prevent from executing FFmpeg for creating thumbnails on these broken 'video' files?

This is my php:

```
$cmd = "ffmpeg -i error.avi 2>&1";
$info = `$cmd`;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($info);
echo '</pre>';
```

this is the output I am getting (very quickly)

```
ffmpeg version 1.0.7 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 19 2013 07:14:44 with gcc 4.7 (Debian 4.7.2-5)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro' --cc='ccache cc' --enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libgsm --enable-libtheora --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree --disable-stripping --enable-libvpx --enable-libschroedinger --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --enable-version3 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-avfilter --enable-libfreetype --enable-libvo-aacenc --disable-decoder=amrnb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libaacplus --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-vda --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-gnutls --enable-frei0r --enable-openssl --enable-libass --enable-libopus --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libdc1394 --disable-altivec --dis  libavutil      51. 73.101 / 51. 73.101
  libavcodec     54. 59.100 / 54. 59.100
  libavformat    54. 29.104 / 54. 29.104
  libavdevice    54.  2.101 / 54.  2.101
  libavfilter     3. 17.100 /  3. 17.100
  libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, avi, from 'error.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : VirtualDubMod 1.5.10.2 (build 2540/release)
  Duration: 01:29:39.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1048 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 640x272 [SAR 1:1 DAR 40:17], 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

So it looks like just creating thumbnails is having problems:

```
exec("ffmpeg -ss 01:11:43 -i error.avi -vframes 1 -s 616x320 -an output_1.jpg 2>&1");
```

Where could be the problem? Thanks for your suggestions!

Btw. I am posting this on SO because I'm not sure where it belongs more than here - I think it could be done somehow by PHP but I'm not really sure.

EDIT: I have added timeout, which "fixes" my problem, but even latest version of FFmpeg 2. stucks on creating thumbnail from broken video files.

```
exec("timeout 5s ffmpeg -ss 01:11:43 -i error.avi -vframes 1 -s 616x320 -an output_1.jpg 2>&1");
```

Comment: Cut out the PHP complexity and resolve any ffmpeg issues first. You need to include the complete console output for the non-working command too.

Comment: It is definitely FFmpeg bug, I was just curious how to prevent this via php, and I think I've got it with timeout parameter